# Get Virtual Root of ASP.NET Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to be able to establish the application root of my Azure website so I can build up all Asp.Net WebAPI calls relative to this.

so if i have an application deployed at 
http://myazuresite.net/ I want it to return http://myazuresite.net/
if
http://myazuresite.net/testsite1/ I want it to return http://myazuresite.net/testsite1/

Originally I used this code below on my _layout which populated the path with Razor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    baseurl = (function (path) {
            return "@HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath";
            }());
</script>
```

I need to build up the url using the root as the _layout could be used from pages in varying levels off the root and also the scripts calling the api's dont live in the same directory as the calling pages.

Comment: `Is this possible in Azure?` It makes no difference whether it's Azure or not. An ASP.NET is still an ASP.NET site, regardless of the hosting service.

Comment: @mason if so i would expect to be able to get something other than "/" for the above which is what i am getting.

Comment: I'm not commenting about whether you've done anything correctly or not. I'm just pointing out that Azure or not makes no difference. Your question seems to imply that this is an Azure specific thing when it's simply about getting the virtual root. I'd remove all Azure references and tags if I were you.